# Disable spymemcached logging in version 2.12

Tags: logging, couchbase, spymemcached

We recently made a version change of `spymemcached` library.
Specifically from version `2.9.1` to `2.12.1`.

It seems that change has produced a log message each second, like the following:

```
2017-04-11 17:20:13,668 Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211} DEBUG [n.s.m.p.a.AsciiMemcachedNodeImpl:72] log | Selecting with delay of 1000ms
2017-04-11 17:20:14,668 Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211} DEBUG [n.s.m.p.a.AsciiMemcachedNodeImpl:72] log | Done dealing with queue.
2017-04-11 17:20:14,668 Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211} DEBUG [n.s.m.p.a.AsciiMemcachedNodeImpl:72] log | Selecting with delay of 1000ms
2017-04-11 17:20:15,669 Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211} DEBUG [n.s.m.p.a.AsciiMemcachedNodeImpl:72] log | Done dealing with queue.
```

What I see in the code of `AsciiMemcachedNodeImpl` class is:

```
71    getLogger().debug("Set up %s with %s keys and %s callbacks", this,
72        pcb.numKeys(), pcb.numCallbacks());
```

I guess there should be a way to configure `spymemcached` logging.
Either it is at runtime on through code.
Does anyone know how to get rid of those logs?

*NOTE*: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610068/spymemcached-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-logging-system) has an answer, though according to its date, it seems for versions `<= 2.9.1`, since `net.spy.log` package and `LoggerImpl` class do not exist anymore. I also cannot find any `setLevel` function in the whole `spymemcached` source code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally fixed this adding this line:

```
<logger name="net.spy.memcached.protocol.ascii" level="info"/>
```

to `logback.xml` process file.